# 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am writing Test Cases for API using Django framework, the GET method seems to be working all right but when it comes to POST error message always shows up:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'.

**Exact error is,**

> res = respo.post({'ticker': 'FIB','open':
>   7.0,'close':8.0,'volume':200})  File "C:\Users\sathya.m\Desktop\mydsite\companies\views.py", line 32, in
>   post    serializer = StockSerializer(data=request.data)
>   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'

**views.py**

```
def post(self,request):
    serializer = StockSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

**tests.py**

```
def test_getDataDetails(self):
    respo = StockList()
    resp = respo.get({'username':'admin','password':'pass'})
    res = respo.post({'ticker': 'FIB','open': 7.0,'close':8.0,'volume':200})
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code,200)
```

Comment: You should be using `request.POST` instead of `request.data`

Comment: Getting below error:AssertionError: 403 != 200

Answer (score 1):

Your view's get and post methods expect a request object as argument, not a dict. You either have to provide this request object yourself or use django's test client (cf the part about testing in the fine manual)

Comment: Thanks Bruno. 
Now i used test client.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. 
Now i used test client.

        c = Client()
        c.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'pass')"
        response = c.post('/stocks/', json={'id': 4,'ticker': 'FIB','open': 7.0,'close':8.0,'volume':200,'owner_id':1})       
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)

Comment: AssertionError: 403 != 200

Comment: @Rubi this is a different problem - and you know what 403 means do you ?

Comment: yes Its forbidden.bcoz it was authenticated..but now after removing the authentication its giving 
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Look at your code. What do you think will happen if  `serializer.is_valid ()` returns `False` ?

Answer (score 1):

Post is working fine, by using this below code:

```
def test_getUserDetails(self):
        url = '/user/'
        data = {"username": "Ramu", "first_name": "Ram", "last_name": "Ram", "email": "ram@techtreeit.com"}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code,201)
```